# javascript - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.iterator is not a function. How to fix such error?

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I'm new to javascript and I'm implementing a binary classification. After converting the csv files of training and test data to arrays, I found this error: 
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.iterator is not a function`

Here is the model fitting:

```
await model.fitDataset(convertedTrainingData, 
   {epochs:100,
    validationData: convertedTestingData,
    callbacks:{
    onEpochEnd: async(epoch, logs) =>{
                             console.log("Epoch: " + epoch + " Loss: " + 
                             logs.loss + " Accuracy: " + logs.acc);
                                  }
                              }});
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: _Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.iterator is not a function_

Comment: what is `convertedTestingData`? Is it an array?

Comment: @random Yes, it is.

Comment: Can you please show how you are creating `convertedTestingData` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from `convertedTestingData` and `convertedTrainingData`. `fitDataset` takes as parameter a `tf.data.Dataset`. An instance of `tf.data.Dataset` has an asynchronous iterator.

if `convertedTestingData` (respectively `convertedTrainingData`) is a js array, it needs to be converted either to a tf.tensor or to a tf.data.Dataset.

- Convert js array to tf.tensor

the method `fit` will be used instead of `fitDataset`

```
model.fit(tf.tensor(features), tf.tensor(labels))
```

- Use tf.data.Dataset

A tf.data.Dataset is created by using a generator.

```
function createDataGenerator(data) {
    return function* dataGenerator() {
      let index = 0;
      while (index < data.length) {
        const feature = getFeatureTensorAtIndex(i) ; // get the feature tensor at the index
        const label = getLabelTensorAtIndex(i); // get the label tensor at the index
        index++;
        yield {xs: feature, ys: label};
      }
    }
}

const training = tf.data.generator(createDataGenerator(convertedTrainingData));
const testing = tf.data.generator(createDataGenerator(convertedTestingData));
```

Then the model can be trained with the dataset `ds`

```
await model.fitDataset(training,
    {
        epochs: 100,
        validationData: testing,
        callbacks: {
            onEpochEnd: async (epoch, logs) => {
                console.log("Epoch: " + epoch + " Loss: " +
                    logs.loss + " Accuracy: " + logs.acc);
            }
        }
    });
```